# Issue to pass value from sub report to main report.Please give me solutions

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I had done below code in crystal report:

1)  I have created one sub report in details section.

2)  In sub report , I have pending amount . I want pass to main report .So I have created formula

WhilePrintingRecords;

Shared CurrencyVar PendingTotal := {@PendingAmount};

3)  In main report I have created another formula

WhilePrintingRecords;

Shared CurrencyVar PendingTotal;

PendingTotal

[please see image to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtIRJ.png)

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please got through the link on how to ask effective questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please explain us according to instructions above what you want to do and what is that we see in the image